# How To Disable JavaScript for a Specific Website in Safari on IOS?

Tags: javascript, safari, ios

I don't think its possible, but hoping the knowledgeable people here will tell me otherwise. Use-case: I have a website added to my home screen from safari on IOS, and I don't want that specific site to use JavaScript. Other browsers on IOS don't (or more likely aren't allowed to) have the 'add to home screen' functionality, so there ability to selectively disable JavaScript on  a per-site basis is not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of a Safari content blocker is the perfect way to set this up.

Here is one such app that is programmed to let you use the native iOS browser and selectively block JavaScript - whether it’s a named script or per site.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pro-script/id1275541103

This isn’t something that’s easy to do yourself from iOS without adding programming or a helper. Another avenue would be to install an app that is a browser, just blocks all JS so you would have to open the link first and then send it to this app.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/no-js/id1062685513